# Optimization: Getting SQL Query out of loop

Tags: java, mysql, sql, loops, optimization

I have two tables with a 1 to n relationship. 
table hobbies has a foreign key to table users called "userid"

```
SELECT * FROM hobbies WHERE userid = 7
```

can have multiple results.
table users contains a list of user profile data and table hobbies contains a list of user hobbies. I want to print a list of profile info of multiple users with hobbies of each user. (hobbies concatenated into one String)
i currently have the following sql queries: (pseudocode):

```
ResultSet result = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users;");

for each returned row: executeQuery("SELECT * FROM hobbies WHERE userid =" + result.getInt("ref"));
```

how do I get the SQL queries out of the loop to optimize performance with a big list of users?

I was trying to do a LEFT JOIN and then doing the WHERE ref= check in java instead of in SQL
problem is that I then get duplicate users and i only want to print one row for each user when processing the result set
also Im not sure if the JOIN is really an improvement in performance, because I have to process more rows.

```
table users
+--------+------+---------+--------+
| userid | name | country | telno  |
+--------+------+---------+--------+
|      1 | John | USA     | 123456 |
|      2 | Max  | Germany | 345678 |
+--------+------+---------+--------+

+--------------+------------+
| userid       |hobby       |
+--------------+------------+
|            1 | football   |
|            1 | basketball |
|            2 | TV         |
|            2 | Music      |
|            2 | football   |
+--------------+------------+

example output:
John, USA, 123456, {football, basketball}
Max, Germany, 345678, {TV, Music, football}
```

Comment: 1) You need to show us the schama for these 2 tables. 2) You need to show an example of the output you want to see

Comment: So you want to concat all your hobbies in 1 user? I think you should let us see your `hobbies` table and `users` table and how do you connect them.

Comment: table users rows: userid, name, country, telNo
table hobbies: userid, hobby
example output:<br>
John, USA, 123456, {football, basketball}<br>
Max, Germany, 345678, {TV, Music, football}

Comment: ugh sorry this looks ugly - how do i corrctly do line breaks

Comment: Don't add comments, edit the question instead. Add the schema, edit whatever you want. The history is kept.

Comment: Using `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`, you get the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably the fastest solution

```
SELECT name, country, telNo, GROUP_CONCAT(hobby)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN hobbies h ON u.id = h.userId
GROUP BY name, country, telNo
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for formatting options.

It's only good for the final output, e.g., if your hobbies contain commas, you wont't be able to parse them uniquely.

Comment: thanks. thats what I needed. didn't lmow the Group_Concat function

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT h.userid, h.allyouneed FROM hobbies h, users u WHERE h.userid =u.userid
```

and get the info in one query

Comment: Read the bit about OP trying JOIN. Why would this be better than a JOIN????

Comment: is equivalent to Join, there is not difference with that.

Comment: There is a difference, but as you say, if he has tried a join what difference would this be from a join

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM hobbies h join users u on h.userid = u.userid WHERE userid = ?"

preparedStatement.setInt(result.getInt("ref"));
```

You can then save all the hobbies to a list similar to the 'Book' example below.

```
public static List<String> selectAll() throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // THE LIST OF BOOKS YOU WILL RETURN
        List<String> books = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT BOOK FROM BOOKs";

        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookshop", "root", "");){

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                String book= rs.getString ("BOOK");
                // ADD BOOK TO THE LIST
                books.add(book);
            }
        }
        finally{
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        // RETURN LIST OF ALL BOOKS
        return books;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.userid,u.name,u.country GROUP_CONCAT(hobby SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM hobbies as h join users as u on h.userid=u.userid 
where h.userid = ? GROUP BY u.userid,u.name,u.country;
```

assumming you have relationship on `hobbies` to `users`. the query will concat the columns of `hobby` of the join tables, and there will be one unique user per row.